# How to integrate favicons-webpack-plugin in Angular 8 projects?

Tags: angular, webpack

I would like to use `jantimon/favicons-webpack-plugin` in Angular 8. I'm using the @angular-builders/custom-webpack package to create a partial webpack configuration.

```
const FaviconsWebpackPlugin = require('favicons-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new FaviconsWebpackPlugin()
  ]
};
```

When I try to generate a build the plugin is not creating the favicons. Do you have any idea of how I can solve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hm, for me generation works for `production` build, but not for `dev` - `ng build --configuration=production`.

Answer (score 1):

`FaviconsWebpackPlugin` generates icons correctly, but for injecting it to the `index.html` HtmlWebpackPlugin is needed. And here there is some problem because since version 8 Angular does not use `HtmlWebPackPlugin` and uses some custom approach of generating `index.html`.

We can inject the icons into `index.html` by setting `index` property in the `angular.json` to the empty string. If `index` property will be empty, then `HtmlWebpackPlugin` will take care of generating and injecting the `index.html` file.

But there is one problem: `HtmlWebpackPlugin` does not inject some of `es5` chunks and the order of chunks isn't correct.